# Pausing and restarting the game in Python (opengl)

Tags: python, pygame, restart

I am still new to python and OpenGL. I wrote a short code to move a car across z-axis and [here](https://ideone.com/RkVtZi) is my fully-written code if needed

What I want to do is to pause the game when the user hits "p", restart when "r" and quit the program when "q" ... Quitting works perfectly but I neither can restart nor pause the game despite all my trials and here is the part I wrote to consider all cases :

```
def keyboard (key,x,y):
  if key == b"q" :
    sys.exit(0)

  if key == b"r" :
    restart_program()

  if key == b"p":
    pause ()
```

P.S. : I tried the Pygame liberary but it doesn't work properly as expected

any help ?!

Comment: Here's a good tutorial that helped me with this http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/.  Basically, you wrap all you game logic into a GameState object, then your "game" become a game state handler.  When you want to pause, your GameState will pass control to a MenuState, causing the GameState to stop being updated.

Comment: The code in my answer is meant to be a template, you would have to move all your current updating and drawing code to a function called `UpdateAllTheThings` *and* you would have to have all your moving parts move by an amount that sclaes with `time_elapsed` (`glTranslatef(-2.5+mov,-0.5,0.5*2.5)` => `glTranslatef(-2.5+(mov*time_elapsed),-0.5,0.5*2.5)`).  This way, passing it 0 will prevent movement, and passing a value (milliseconds or whatever) will scale movement with time since last update.

Answer (score 0):

See the link on my comment for a more complete way of handling pausing, but you could also just refactor your drawing code to something along the lines of:

```
elapsed_time = 0
paused = False

def update():
  start_time = time.time()

  if key == b"r" :
    paused = False

  if key == b"p":
    paused = True

  if paused:
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
  else:
    elapsed_time = 0

  UpdateAllTheThings(elapsed_time)

while True:
  update()
```

Then, while updating all the moving parts of your system, you will want to scale each move by the amount to time passed. By having a separate `update()` function which takes elapsed time as a parameter, you can simulate pausing by passing it `0`.  The [system of game states](http://%20gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c.) makes this far more robust and extensible, it's worth learning about.